# androidx.annotation.NonNull Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'

Tags: androidx, android-annotations

I have an issue after I deleted and updated some libraries from my project when I open any class that imports **androidx.annotation.NonNull;** I see error that **Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'**

I do a search and found that I should add to Gradle **implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0"**, but the error still appears.

When I try to click Alt+Enter he changes the import to
**import io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull;**

My Gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0"
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:3.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:6.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed after I updated the android studio version!